# Time out issues posting questions

Tags: support

I created a question on Stack Overflow and clicked the "Post Your Question" button and got an error indicating something I missed. 
 I corrected it and tried to post the question, but I got "You can only post once every 20 minutes" notification. The mechanism that validates the form should not force me to wait 20 minutes to try to repost my quesiton. 
What if during the fix I missed something else. I have to wait another 20 minutes?  40 minutes of waiting is just too much.  I understand that this may be in place to keep people from spamming, however the validation needs to be fixed so that a person can correct the question and submit.

I usually post questions at the end of the day if I can help it after I have done all the research I can think of.  So I dont want to have to wait an additional 20 minutes.

Please fix how question form on Stackoverflow works on form validation errors.

Comment: The "You can only post once every 20 minutes" suggests that your first attempt actually made it through.

Comment: Isn't there anything faster than a microwave?

Comment: @ daniel according to the error message the form did not on the first attempt... wierd....  also so that there are no misunderstanding... I truly enjoy Stackoverflow.  I recommend the site to all my peer developers... *shameless flattery*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone else sharing your IP address posted a question right before you tried to. We rate-limit posts from new users based on IP to prevent various forms of abuse, so when you tried to post you hit the same thing.

Go ahead and try again - your question *should* go through now.